# ListPolarPlot: 0 Degree at vertical axis

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to have ListPolarPlot start plotting at the vertical axis?
By Default ListPolarPlot gives this result:

```
ListPolarPlot[Reverse[Range[20]], PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}]
```

[image]

But I want it to look like this (rotated with `Rotate[%,1/2pi]`:
[image]

Just rotating the graphic probably is the easiest way, but adding ticks and legends is a crime... I am hoping for a way to simply set the starting angle.

Specifying angles at each data point and adding 1/2pi does not solve my problem because the angles in the PolarAxes would be off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make rotate transform like this. And change some options of `ListPolarPlot`. I modified the `PolarTicks` option.

```
rotatePolar[a_List] := Module[{l = Length[a]},
  Table[{2 Pi*(i - 1)/l + Pi/2, a[[i]]}, {i, l}]
  ]

ListPolarPlot[rotatePolar[Reverse[Range[20]]], PolarAxes -> True,
 PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 20},
 PolarTicks -> {Drop[
    Table[{i, Mod[i - 90 Degree, 360 Degree]}, {i, 0, 360 Degree, 
      15 Degree}], -1], Automatic}
 ]
```

> [image]

Comment: Ah, the trick with the PolarTicks is very clever! :) Thanks a lot.