# List polar plot 0° at bottom

Tags: plotting

can anyone please help me with ListPolarPlot?
I have these data

```
data = {{-114.95, 10.35}, {-110.0, 12.57}, {-105.0, 15.39}, {-100.0, 18.94}, {-95.0, 23.44}, {-90.0, 29.22}, {-85.0, 37.2}, {-80.0, 46.8}, {-75.0, 57.5}, {-70.0, 68.4}, {-65.0, 78.9}, {-60.0, 88.4}, {-55.0, 97.6}, {-50.0, 107.2}, {-45.0, 117.9}, {-40.0, 129.3}, {-35.0, 140.5}, {-30.05, 150.3}, {-25.0, 158.1}, {-20.0, 163.7}, {-15.05, 167.3}, {-10.0, 169.3}, {-5.0, 170.3}, {-0.05, 170.4}, {4.95, 169.4}, {9.95, 167.2}, {14.95, 163.5}, {19.95, 158.0}, {24.95, 150.2}, {30.0, 140.1}, {34.95, 128.4}, {39.95, 116.2}, {44.95, 104.8}, {49.95, 94.5}, {54.95, 84.8}, {59.95, 74.9}, {64.95, 64.5}, {69.95, 53.8}, {74.95, 43.4}, {79.95, 34.0}, {84.95, 26.5}, {89.95, 21.25}, {94.95, 17.22}, {99.95, 13.98}, {104.95, 11.39}, {109.95, 8.49}, {114.95, 6.89}}
```

I have managed to create a ListPolarPlot using

```
data2 = {#[[1]]*Pi/180, #[[2]]} & /@ data
```

and

```
ListPolarPlot[data2, PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, Joined -> True, PolarGridLines -> True]
```

[image]

The thing is I need to have 0°  at bottom of the plot (where now is 270°). Does anyone know, how to rotate it?

Thank you.

Walter

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58286/listpolarplot-0-degree-at-vertical-axis

Comment: @AnjanKumar


does not work for me.

When i try

    rotatePolar[a_List] := 
 Module[{l = Length[a]}, 
  Table[{2 Pi*(i - 1)/l + Pi/2, a[[i]]}, {i, l}]]

ListPolarPlot[rotatePolar[data2], PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarGridLines -> True, PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 200}, 
 PolarTicks -> {Drop[
    Table[{i, Mod[i - 270 Degree, 360 Degree]}, {i, 0, 360 Degree, 
      15 Degree}], -1], Automatic}]

then the axes are correctly oriented, 0° is at bottom of the Plot, but the plot is blank, no data shown.

Do you know where might be problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the rotated plot, we have to change the ticks of `ListPolarPlot` using `PolarTicks`, and the data points by `270 deg`.

```
data2 = {(#[[1]] + 270)*Pi/180, #[[2]]} & /@ data; 
ListPolarPlot[data2, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {Drop[
    Table[{i, Mod[i - 270 Degree, 360 Degree]}, {i, 0, 360 Degree, 
      15 Degree}], -1], Automatic}, Joined -> True, 
 PolarGridLines -> True]
```

[image]

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much!