# Suggestions for using ScalingFunction in ListPolarPlot to rotate cooridinate system by 90 degrees?

Tags: graphics

I have a list of {phi, rVals} that need to be plotted in a clockwise manner with the 0 Degree tick at the top.

I hoped ScalingFunctions would have solved my issue, but it didn't -- see attached graphic to see plotted data values are increasing in a clockwise fashion, but the 0 degree is at the right, and the outer-ticks moves in a counter-clockwise fashion.

---

```
offset = .1
data = Table[{{phi, offset += .1 }, {phi, (offset + .5)}}, {phi, 0 Degree, 360 Degree, 30 Degree}];

ListPolarPlot[Tooltip@data, ScalingFunctions -> {None,"Reverse"}, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 3, PolarAxes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: For 1 and 2 look at the `PolarTicks` and `PolarAxesOrigin` options.

Comment: See also [ListPolarPlot: 0 Degree at vertical axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58286/27951)

Comment: @MarcoB -- thanks. Although I'm still searching for the solution for question 2, the following two options to ListPolarPlot directly addresses my questions 1 and 3 above. `PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}`